# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer' in Python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, notifications, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to write a program notify.py (location: desktop) that uses plyer library to get a notification on windows 10. I used pip install plyer and am using vs code to run the program but I get an error saying :

```
" from plyer import notification
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer' " .
```

Here's my code:

```
from plyer import notification
        
title = "Greetings!"
message = "Don't forget to take a break!"
        
notification.notify(title = title, messgae = message, app_icon = None, timeout = 10, toast = False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plyer` is not built-in module in Python, so before importing it in your code, you should first install it.

Open a **new** **integrated Terminal** and run

```
pip show plyer
```

to check if its location is `\your current interpreter\lib\site-packages`. If is, reload window, then the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer'` should go away. If not, please install it again.

Comment: I first installed Plyer and then did the whole thing.

Comment: I followed this website:  https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/create-desktop-notifier-using-python-6dab0a1c348c

Comment: @Annie, please follow my answer to check if you installed module correctly in current environment.

Comment: That worked! I uninstalled and installed it again and ran the code. Thanks!