# Trying to installing/import plyer module

Tags: python, module, importerror

I installed the plyer module it said ...

```
pip install plyer
Requirement already satisfied: plyer in *insert path here*
```

So, I think that the module is already installed so I put in the code ...

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify( title = "Reminder ⏰", message="Break is over time to work..." ,  timeout=10)
```

But, it returns an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\#####\Code\Python\Reminder\Reminder.py", line 2, in <module>
    from plyer import notification
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer'
```

There is **NO** module named **'plyer'** like what someone please help me...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69129793/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-plyer-in-python. Check out this post!!!

Comment: I did everything that it said and it did not work I uninstalled the module and everything. It is located in `\lib\site-packages` too

Answer (score 0):

Well,I used to meet the same problem and  I recommend that you should check the point below:

1. If you are using VScode then check if you are under the security mode,which need you to believe the author or the dir in VScode
2. Check the version of Python and pip wheter the module is truly installed to the version of Python that you are using.(The virtual environment can also cause the same question)
3. Maybe you can try `pip3 install -U plyer`to install it

Hope that can help you.